# Why does validation of nested attributes not work on create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

In my Rails 6 app I have the following setup:

```
class Quote < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :service_items, :dependent => :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :service_items, :allow_destroy => true

  validate :no_more_than_two_currencies

  def currencies
    service_items.pluck(:currency).uniq
  end

private

  def no_more_than_two_currencies
    if currencies.length > 2
      errors.add(:base, "Only two currencies are allowed")
    end
  end

end
```

Unfortunately, the validation only works on **update**, not on **create**.

For some reason, `service_items.pluck(:currency).uniq` doesn't return any currencies before a record has actually been saved.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: The problem is that `pluck` is used to create a database query. Since the service items are not saved it returns no rows. You want `#map`, `#select` or any of the other methods from enumerable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `service_items` aren't yet added to the database, therefore `pluck` doesn't return anything useful. You can access this with `map`, which uses the in-memory object.

```rb
def currencies
  service_items.map(&:currency).uniq
end
```